# Create a fixed set of relative points around central point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing

In support of some watershed work, I need to force flow into several valid sinks that I have burned into my DEM. [Flow direction](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/flow-direction.htm) and [flow accumulation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/flow-accumulation.htm) really don't like sinks so trouble is that the flow accumulation at my sinks is zero and the several flow lines to each of the sinks do not converge.  as a result, **my pour points fail to capture all flow**.

Since **all flow lines terminate at the 8 pixels immediately adjacent to my sinks**, I have proposed placing 8 additional pour points at fixed positions relative to my current points such that:

*For each input point, 8 new points with the same attributes are to be created to match the fixed pixel spacing of my DEM.*

*to put it another way, for each input pixel (yellow) I want the digitize the 8 surrounding ones (cyan)*

[image]

**are there existing tools or processes that I can use to accomplish this?**

I asked these questions yesterday to bring me to this thought process

[Understanding ArcGIS Flow accumulation result?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317075/understanding-arcgis-flow-accumulation-result?noredirect=1#comment515757_317075)

[Understanding ArcGIS Flow Direction pixel values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317073/understanding-arcgis-flow-direction-pixel-values?noredirect=1#comment515773_317073)

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly elegant, but might get the job done:

- Buffer input points to the pixel size(purple).
- find the envelope of the buffer.
- convert the envelope to a line (yellow).
- find the corner points (blue) of envelope.
- split the envelope line at those corner points.
- then find the mid points (red) of the split envelope lines.
- Copy/Paste the corners and midpoints to a feature class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with trigonometry, below is some sample code to get you going.

```py
# Creates an in_memory featureclass of points based around a known centre point
# This code assumes your data is projected into metres, so your raster must not be in WGS84.
#
# Duncan Hornby (ddh@geodata.soton.ac.uk)
#
# 8/6/21

import arcpy
import math

# You need to set the spatial reference to your raster, this example is UTM 42N
# Set the cell size to be the same as your raster
# Choose an appropriate output location, this example use IN_MEMORY
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(32642)
rastercellsize = 220
outfc = r"IN_MEMORY\points"

# Create the centrepoint
# You need to update these coordinates
CentreX = 344132
CentreY = 3979917

lstPoints = list()
lstAngles = [0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315]

# Compute hypotenuse length based upon raster cell size
hypotenuse = math.sqrt(math.pow(rastercellsize,2) + math.pow(rastercellsize,2))

# Main loop for creating points around the centre point
for angle in lstAngles:
    if angle in [0,90,180,270]:
        X = rastercellsize * math.cos(math.radians(90 - angle))
        Y = rastercellsize * math.sin(math.radians(90 - angle))
    else:
        X = hypotenuse * math.cos(math.radians(90 - angle))
        Y = hypotenuse * math.sin(math.radians(90 - angle))

    # Create a point then convert it into a pointGeometry so you can set its spatial reference
    P = arcpy.Point(CentreX + X, CentreY  + Y)
    newPoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(P,sr,False,False)

    # Store point in list
    lstPoints.append(newPoint)

# Save out list
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = True
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lstPoints,outfc)
```

Edit it as needed and run it from the Python console in ArcMap, this would generate:

[image: Output]

I've used the Copy Features tool to store the points. An obvious improvement to this code is to create a FeatureClass, add appropriate fields (for example ID and angle) then use an [InsertCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) to store the data, this would give you more control.